Missing Display configuration in new archlinux system
I've been using Arch Linux for the past few years but I've installed it on a new system and am having a problem getting the display to work properly when I start a window manager.

If I run hyprland or startx the screen turns blank and I can't do anything until I reset my computer.
If I try to run i3 or brave-browser I get an error like:
i3: Cannot open display

or
brave: Missing X server or $DISPLAY



I'm using a new computer: ROG zephyrus G16. I have a fresh install of Arch using archinstall.
Thanks for anyone with ideas.

What do you find in ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log after a startx? (not a sudo startx I hope?)

[ 1201.873] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed [ 1201.873] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running [ 1201.874] (EE) Fatal server error: [ 1201.874] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) [ 1201.874] (EE) [ 1201.874] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information. [ 1201.874] (EE) [ 1201.874] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Also asked my question here with more details:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2212377#p2212377

I read your other post.  Please provide the output of lspci | grep vga or the same with lshw  You should end up with 2 Graphics Cards, an intel based one and the NVIDIA based one. The X Server is unaware of the NVIDIA card until the intel one is configured and switched off using sftware like PRIME Renderer.  See: ArchWiki- Optimus and NVIDIA's Technology Entry. The X Server expects to use the Intel card to produce visuals as your Xorg log confirms.
